# Sencha Touch - switching between views

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i am trying to make the same app with the miamicode, i am at step 3
http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/

i try to make the button that goes to new note (switch to a new screen and create a new note)

the code at the example is this:

```
   onNewNoteCommand: function () {
   console.log("onNewNoteCommand");
   var now = new Date();
   var noteId = (now.getTime()).toString() + (this.getRandomInt(0, 100)).toString();
   var newNote = Ext.create("NotesApp.model.Note", {
          id: noteId,
            dateCreated: now,
            title: "",
            narrative: ""
        });

        this.activateNoteEditor(newNote);
    }
```

the activateNotesList function is this :

```
activateNotesList: function () {

   Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getNotesListView(), this.slideRightTransition);
```

on my own example i try just to go the editview without passing data.
so i try this:

```
onNewNoteCommand:function()

{
var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();

 // Ext.Viewport.add(noteEditor);  also tried this.

Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(noteEditor);
```

that code runs with no errors but the screen doesn't change. 
any suggestion? whats the difference on add ?

how do i set the viewport (haven't created any custom viewport) to card? is this the problem that setactiveitem doesn't work? any other way to switch between views?

Answer (score 1):

Are there some errors in google chrome browser's console? `Ctrl+Shift+J` to open.

Also you have to check if noteEditor equals Object or Number.

From sencha docs: `setActiveItem( Object/Number activeItem )`

Comment: well i got no errors.


but the type of noteEditor is undifiend ...
 this is how my noteEditor starts:


Ext.define("noteditor.view.NoteEditor", {

    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",

    alias: "widget.noteeditor",

 requires : "Ext.form.FieldSet",
 
 config : {layout: {type:'vbox'}},
 initialize : function () {.....

and on controller i have a reference 
Ext.define("noteditor.controller.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
 config: {
  refs: {
   notesListContainer: "Main",
   noteEditor: "noteeditor"
      },
  control: {
     
   }},

Comment: you should write like that: Ext.define("noteditor.view.NoteEditor", { extend: "Ext.form.Panel", xtype: 'noteeditor'..... and your ref noteEditor will not be undefined.

Comment: console.log (typeof(this.noteEditor));
i typed this inside button action. also changes alias with xtype. but no luck... still undefined.. i tried on some function, it work ok.
also tried typeof(noteditor.views.Notes) shouldn't my view be there?

Comment: check the names:  noteditor.view.Notes or noteditor.view.NoteEditor? do you use view in you names or views (have to use view also as name of folder, not views, etc).

Comment: Also the best way to study sencha touch is to explore sencha touch 2 example's code. Like oreilly, geocongress, touchtweets.

Comment: my bad. 
i use noteditor.view.NoteEditor
(typeof(noteditor.view.noteEditor)
i use view.
undefined result :S